# get all rows having a column value greater than a threshold

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, numeric-data

I have a file with a lot of rows and columns but the number of columns are not same in all rows. I want to extract all rows having delta value greater than 0.02

```
Point          Fanout   cap   trans   delta   incr   Path
----------------------------------------------------------
row1             1       0.02  0.01   0.00     0.03   0.04
row2             2       0.04
row3             1       0.01  0.02    0.04    0.05   0.06
row4                     0.03
row5                           0.04     0.05    0.07  0.07
```

Can anybody help? How to grep all those rows and corresponding delta value?

Comment: Delta values always in the 5th field ?

Comment: How are your fields defined? Are they tab-separated? Space-separated? For example, how many fields does row2 have? Is it 3 or is it 7 with 4 of those blank? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Answer (score 9):

As pointed out in comments, for a delimiter other than space (i.e tab as seems to be your case) bellow solutions would work ok.
If delimiter is space bellow solutions will not work. You need to clarify what is the real fields separator.

```
awk -F"\t" '$5>0.02' file
#or
awk -F"\t" 'NR==1{print;next}$5>0.02' file #to keep the header
#or
awk -F"\t" 'NR==1 || $5>0.02' file  #also keeps header as advised in comments
#or 
awk -F"\t" 'NR<=2 || $5>0.02' file   #keep header and dashed row bellow header as advised by @Sundeep
```

If you are in doubt about the format of the numeric values, you could even try

```
awk -F"\t" '($5*1)>0.02' file
```

Comment: for header: `awk 'NR==1 || $5>0.02'` or `awk 'NR<=2 || $5>0.02'` to include the second line with dashes as well

Comment: This won't work if the file is space-separated. For example, try a row where the only non-empty field is the "point" and the "delta". Awk will think the delta is $2 and skip the row. Unless the OP clarifies how their fields are defined, this isn't going to be easy to answer at all.

Comment: @terdon Yeap, good point. Better to clarify this in my answer. Will work with a delimiter other than space, since with single space things will get weird.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to process are `PrimeTime` timing reports for fixing your `timing violations` or `crosstalk noise violations` then I would advise you to go for the commands (Tcl) that are provided for by your particular `EDA` tool.

Reinventing the wheel will not really be the way to go.