# get all rows having a column value greater than or equal to particular value

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have to extract the values which are greater than or equal to 0.01 from column number 6 of tab-delimited file(My files contain more than 6 columns). I had tried with following code

```bsh
for i in $(find ./ `pwd` -name "BC_4_*_*shift.txt" ); do
    awk -F"\t" 'NR==1 || $6>=0.01' $i > $i"_"ctdna_freq.txt;
done
```

to write this code I had taken help from [get all rows having a column value greater than a threshold](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356080/get-all-rows-having-a-column-value-greater-than-a-threshold), Using this code I am able extract values from 6th column which are greater than 0.01 but I am not able to extract the values which are equal to 0.01
following is my input file

```
chr     pos         ref var p.val       freq.var
chr19   9074573     A   C   6.73E-22    0.586593469
chr19   9091288     G   T   5.96E-188   0.508732726
chr8    124518636   C   T   9.55E-21    0.00005
chr12   56490398    G   T   0.005271732 0.010003218
chr12   56477619    G   A   1.40E-15    0.010001069
chr12   56477619    G   A   1.40E-15    0.010001069
chr3    52677261    C   T   5.13E-06    0.01
chr5    67591010    A   G   4.82E-23    0.01
```

Expected output

```
chr     pos         ref var p.val       freq.var
chr19   9074573     A   C   6.73E-22    0.586593469
chr19   9091288     G   T   5.96E-188   0.508732726
chr12   56490398    G   T   0.005271732 0.010003218
chr12   56477619    G   A   1.40E-15    0.010001069
chr12   56477619    G   A   1.40E-15    0.010001069
chr3    52677261    C   T   5.13E-06    0.01
chr5    67591010    A   G   4.82E-23    0.01
```

Comment: cannot reproduce, the `awk` works fine for me, outputting lines with 0.01, maybe break it down (remove for loop etc., so try to reproduce the issue with a minimal script, sth like `awk 'NR==1 || $6>=0.01' file`

Comment: What awk version are you using? On GNU awk 5.0.1 it seems to work as you would expect. I suspect it might be a floating point precision error, try with `awk 'NR==1 || $6>=0.0099'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while IFS= read -r i; do
    awk -F'\t' 'NR==1 || $6>=0.01' "$i" > "${i}_ctdna_freq.txt"
done < <(find . -name 'BC_4_*_*shift.txt')
```

or:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
find . -name 'BC_4_*_*shift.txt' |
xargs -n 1 -I {} awk -F'\t' 'NR==1 || $6>=0.01' "{}" > "{}_ctdna_freq.txt"
```

Don't do `for i in ...`, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001, and do always quote your variables, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes. Run all your shell scripts through http://shellcheck.net until you're familiar with the fundamentals.

Comment: For your second example, may I recommend adding the `-print0` option to the `find` command and the `-0` option to the `xargs` command. I know that it is not necessary in the OPs use case, but others looking for a similar problem may be dealing with "not-so-well-behaved" filenames where this might be an issue ...

Comment: @AdminBee I thought about it but then it's GNU-specific for both tools and like you say, it's not necessary in the OPs case.

Comment: Ok, valid point ...

Answer (score 0):

I put your data into a file known as `data1.txt`

Similarly, I made manual modifications and made many files.

This code does what you want in all. But it outputs to a single file.

```
find . -name "data*.txt" -type f -exec awk 'NR==1 || $6>=0.01' {} + >>output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

command

```
awk '$6 >= 0.01' file.txt
```

output

```
chr     pos         ref var p.val       freq.var
chr19   9074573     A   C   6.73E-22    0.586593469
chr19   9091288     G   T   5.96E-188   0.508732726
chr12   56490398    G   T   0.005271732 0.010003218
chr12   56477619    G   A   1.40E-15    0.010001069
chr12   56477619    G   A   1.40E-15    0.010001069
chr3    52677261    C   T   5.13E-06    0.01
chr5    67591010    A   G   4.82E-23    0.01
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python

k=open('file.txt','r')
k.readline()
print ("chr     pos         ref var p.val       freq.var")
for i in k:
    q=i.split(' ')[-1]
    if (float(q) >= 0.01):
        print (i.strip())



output

chr     pos         ref var p.val       freq.var
chr19   9074573     A   C   6.73E-22    0.586593469
chr19   9091288     G   T   5.96E-188   0.508732726
chr12   56490398    G   T   0.005271732 0.010003218
chr12   56477619    G   A   1.40E-15    0.010001069
chr12   56477619    G   A   1.40E-15    0.010001069
chr3    52677261    C   T   5.13E-06    0.01
chr5    67591010    A   G   4.82E-23    0.01
```